# Getting java.net.SocketException: Connection reset while using driver.close()

Tags: java, selenium, driver

> July 10, 2022 11:43:52 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
> WARNING: Connection reset
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
> at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
> at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:258)
> at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132)
> at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

The code is below. It is not happening for driver.quit() but why?

```
public class ValidateTitleTest extends Base{

WebDriverWait wait;
JavascriptExecutor j;
public static Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Base.class.getName());

@BeforeTest
public void Initialize() throws Exception {
    driver = InitializeDriver();
    log.info("Driver is initilized");
    driver.get(property.getProperty("url"));
    log.info("Navigated to HomePage");
    wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
}

@Test
public void ValidatePageTitle() throws Exception {
    //Accessing diff class method by creating object or inheritance i.e extends
    LandingPage l = new LandingPage(driver,wait);   
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(l.getTitle()));
    j = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    j.executeScript("window.stop();");
    Assert.assertTrue(l.getTitle().getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Featured Courses"));
    log.info("Successfully Validated Text");
}

@AfterTest
public void TearDown() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.close();
    log.info("Browser Clossing");
}
```

}